# Handling retraction when using a mixing extruder (2 in 1 out)

Tags: marlin, extrusion, simplify3d, retraction

I have a Zonestar Z5FM2 running Marlin 1.1.8 with a mixing extruder.

That is, 2 extruder stepper motors feeding a 2-in 1-out hotend (similar to the E3D cyclops).

I'm slicing with Simplify3D and I have set up:

- T0 set to the first extruder;
- T1 set to the second extruder;
- T2 set to a virtual extruder consisting of a 50/50 mix of extruder 1 and 2(made by having `M163 S0 P50` followed by `M164 S2` in the start code)

I was wondering how you handle the retraction. Currently only the active tool (e.g. extruder motor 1 when using T1) retracts, which leads to a lot of oozing since the filament in the unused half is still applying some pressure.

I read that for a setup like mine it is necessary to get both extruders to retract. How do I do that?

I've seen the documentation for programming `G10/G11` firmware retract with `M207` but there does not seem to be a way to specify the tool to use.

I could make a find-and-replace post processing script in Simplify3D to replace retracts of T0 or T1 with retracts of T2 (so both motors retract), but then how would I get it to switch back to the proper original tool when resuming printing?

Is there a way to address an extruder directly in `G1` commands (so I could force both to retract), or temporarily switch a tool for just one command (so I could switch tool for the retract command only and it would go back to printing with the previous tool afterwards)?

Comment: In Slic3r and Prusa Slicer 2.0, you can set a seperate retract value for when the extruder is inactive.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this post](https://forum.simplify3d.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=6684) on the S3D Forums that seem to have some interesting information on custom scripting within Simplify3D. While this doesn't seem to SPECIFICALLY address the question you've got, it looks like there's a "Retraction Scripts" tab that you could probably leverage your T2 tool inside of, using "OLDTOOL" instead of "NEWTOOL".

For additional information on what variables are available, I found [a different forum post here](https://forum.simplify3d.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1959) that seems to have some documentation on Simplify3D's built-in script variables. Additionally, from the GCode in the first link's example scripts, it *appears* that you should be able to actually address M-commands to individual extruders (such as T2 in your case) simply by adding "T(x)" as a parameter to the individual command. I just ran a quick test on my own Marlin-based printer with a 2in-1out hotend, and I was not able to get it to address G1 commands to specific E motors without switching tools.

All in all I think you should be able to use the custom scripts available in S3D to accomplish what you want by switching tools in the layer change script, but aside from that, I don't know what options you have available with that specific software chain.